# Swagger UI - Try it Out Button Not Showing

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using Swagger 2.0 and the Try It Out button is not showing for my methods.
My HTML is same as [Petstore Swagger](http://petstore.swagger.io).

I am not getting any console errors.
My Swagger.json is here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/novastorm123/abapswaggerNW7.0/master/swagger_70.json

```
<body>
<div id="swagger-ui"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
 url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/novastorm123/abapswaggerNW7.0/master/swagger_70.json",
dom_id: "#swagger-ui",
supportedSubmitMethods: ['get'],
presets: [
SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
Array.isArray(SwaggerUIStandalonePreset) ? SwaggerUIStandalonePreset :       SwaggerUIStandalonePreset.default
],
plugins: [
SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
],
layout: "StandaloneLayout"
})
window.ui = ui
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Had the same problem. In my case `host` was missing in the config — next to `basePath`.

Answer (score 0):

The **`host` setting might be missing** in your Swagger configuration file, as @alexvetter also pointed out in the comments. Logically, no host, no need of "Try it out" button as it has no domain to make a request to.